# EasyHook alternatives for C#

Tags: c#, hook, easyhook

after much searching of a way to create a hook into an external application in C#, I stumbled upon EasyHook, which would be ideal. Unfortunately there is zero community around, the software is not maintained since 2008, does not seem to work under Visual Studio 10, and gives problems under Visual Studio 2008.

I understand that a programmer willing to do such a low level work is normally proficient in C/C++, however if possible I'd like to avoid having to learn how to code in C++ under Windows ;)

I have also found Deviare, but it is still beta and it seems to be commercial. It can be an alternative.

Does anyone know an alternative library?

Thanks

Comment: The download page for Deviare says it's free after filling out a form: http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/download

Comment: Very old question I know but just to update, EasyHook does now support Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4. There is a beta release in the works.

Answer (score 5):

I'm in a similar situation, I've been trying EasyHook and [Deviare](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) and I like much more Deviare because the database feature for datatypes is great and last version works very well with C#.
The problem is that Deviare is commercial and doesn't support x64.

Currently, I'm stuck with EasyHook with some incompatibilities with .NET 3.5 (I'm asking about that issue in a post here).

Comment: Deviare 2.0 supports 64 bits http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/features

Answer (score 2):

A recent and deep technical discussion about EasyHook/Microsoft Detours/Nektra's Deviare similarities and differences is available in the Reverse Engineering subreddit [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/22crn0/gpl_alternative_library_to_microsoft_detours_for/).

Answer (score -1):

How about [Detours](http://rootbiez.blogspot.com/2010/04/hooking-detours.html) from Microsoft Research.